# Create java client from WSDL

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, wsimport

I was given a WSDL file as well as the URL of corresponding web service. I know that I must convert the WSDL file to Java classes, using a tool like wsimport. But after that, I am quite lost. How do I write the client code to use these generated classes? I have been googling and still quite not sure about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache CXF wsdl2java command to convert wsdl file to java file. After that usage is quite simple as follows(and there are may tutorials available):

```
HelloService service = new HelloService();

Hello client = service.getHelloHttpPort(); 
String result = client.sayHi("Joe");
```

WSDL2Java link:      http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html
CXF Client Tutorial: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/how-do-i-develop-a-client.html

Thanks.

Comment: There is also an Axis2 wsdl2java.bat. Is this the same as the CXF one?

Comment: yup, they are the same but the output stub files differ in ways you can use them.